# Issue in fetching data from joined tables

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have four tables in my database named as 'user_login', 'store', 'admin', 'store_product'. when I try fetch data from user_login table, it does not work.
My codes are as below:

View form:

```
 <form method="get">
Enter city: <input type ="text" name="city">
Enter search keyword: <input type="text" name="searchB">
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function search()
{
    $this->load->model('searchmodel');
    $fc = $this->input->get('city');
    $sb = $this->input->get('searchB');
    $rr=$this->searchmodel->searchDetail($sb,$fc);
    $data['results'] = $rr;
    $this->load->view('search/detailResults',$data);
}
```

Model

```
public function searchDetail($data,$datacity){
     $this->db->select();
     $this->db->from('user_login');
     $this->db->join('store', 'store.vendor_bri = user_login.bri', 'full outer');        
     $this->db->join('admin', 'admin.bri = user_login.bri', 'full outer');       
     $this->db->join('store_product', 'store_product.vendor_bri = user_login.bri', 'full outer');

     $this->db->having('store.town', $datacity);
     $this->db->or_having('store.country', $datacity);
     $this->db->like('user_login.business_name',$data, 'both');
     $this->db->or_like('user_login.business_type', $data);
     $this->db->or_like('user_login.speciality', $data);
     $this->db->or_like('store.locality', $data);        
     $this->db->or_like('store.vendor_bri', $data,'none');
     $this->db->or_like('store_product.pd_universal_code', $data,'none');
     $this->db->or_like('store_product.pd_name', $data);
     $this->db->or_like('store_product.pd_description', $data);
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result_array(); 

}
```

Comment: Is there any errors?

Comment: No error. it gives result if there is more than one entity is available. that means if 'John' is available in two or more row then it gives the result but if 'John' is available at in a single row than it does not give any result.